# What does NOR mean in this contet?

Tags: meaning, adverbs, conjunctions, lyrics

So I found the lyrics of the song and trying to understand their meaning better.
What does NOR mean in such context?

> Let the Priests of the Raven of dawn no longer in deadly black, with hoarse note, curse the sons of joy!
>
> Nor his accepted brethren, whom, tyrant, he calls free: lay the bound or build the roof.
>
> Nor pale religious Letchery call that virginity, that wishes but acts not!

1. Does it mean, that they will curse the sons of joy, but they will NOT curse "his accepted brethren"?
2. Does it mean that they will NOT curse "pale religious Letchery", that speaks of virginity (this sentence is really confusing and I am really not sure how to understand it)

or

they will curse "pale religious Letchery", but not the ones who are called virgins by it?

Or how to understand it??
Do they say that letchery is bad, or that virginity is bad??
Can someone explain please?

Song:
Theatres Des Vampires - Pale Religious Letchery

Comment: 'And let not ...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Let A no longer do X, nor B [any longer] do Y, nor C do Z". As Edwin says, 'nor' substitutes for 'and let not'.

I think the writer means that religious puritans should not call people virgins when they wish for sex but haven't done it. The first 'that' means something like 'that state of mind'.

Comment: Hey, I suppose you are right, but did you really mean "religious puritans"? I mean the word puritan (as I know (correct me if I am wrong)) means - the person, who has an old fashioned religious world view, so to say. And in this context "religious puritans" are the keepers of virginity till marriage. But the song (and your comment in general, as I see (correct me if I am wrong)) is about "religious lechery". So the religious people, who were seduced by lust. And that they should not call virginity, by its name, for it is purity (am I getting it right?).

Comment: In short, didnt you mean the opposite to the word "puritans"?

Comment: Literary interpretation is outside the scope of this website; I was merely trying to explain the grammatical sense of the passage. But I imagine the writer refers to people who make a show of puritanism but are secretly lecherous.